# Maps on iPhone gives me completely wrong distance estimates

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, maps

Let's say I look up "Coffee Shops". It gives me a list of coffee shops around and their distances. But when I choose a coffee shop and press on it, it gives me a completely different distance.

For example, one of the coffee shops in the initial list Maps shows me is supposedly at a distance of 700m. However when I "click" on that coffee shop, it then shows a distance of 2km (almost 3 times more).

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a speculation and based on observation, but it seems that Maps will use the last place the iPhone "checked in" as point where it thinks you are to calculate distances.

When you click/tap on the specific entry, it then gets the actual GPS coordinates to then draw the map/calculate directions.

The way I solved the issue was to search for my place of interest in Bing (yeah, the [Bing App](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-bing-search/id345323231)) because it gets the actual GPS coordinates, runs the search, and then hands off to Apple Maps.